# .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)

Tags: java, android

I have generated my signed apk with this code below.
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
and uploaded to playstore for one year. It is showing real ads in case of other than test device. It is also earning revenues without any warning from Admob. In fact i did the same for two different apps so far. 
My question is, is it really compulsory removing .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) method before generating signed apk? Will it cause threat my earning further or will it result any violation of Admob policy if user clicks real ads on their device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.addTestDevice` call should only be used to test ads and could violate policies. If you aren't testing, you should remove this call and operate normally. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: I just commented out that particular method and uploaded to play store. will it be ok??

Comment: Yes, it should be okay. As long as you don't use it publicly, it is going to be okay.